# How to convert correct date from m-d-Y to Y-m-d using PHP

Tags: php

Since i read another few topic with similar problem i dont understand what is wrong in my situation
date is sorted with - in both case so date 03-14-2020 should become 2020-14-03 but become 1970-01-01

```
$dates = explode(" / ", $this->input->post('date'));
print_r($dates);

Array ( [0] => 03-14-2020 [1] => 03-20-2020 )


    $newDate = array(
       'start'      => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[0])),
       'end'        => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[1]))
    );
print_r($newDate)

Array ( [start] => 1970-01-01 [end] => 1970-01-01 )
```

even this way is not showing correct

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $dates[0]);
print_r($date->format('Y-m-d'));
2021-02-03
```

Comment: The date format is incorrect... YYYY-MM-DD is expected.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz give a example of correct one, please

Comment: I did... please make sure to read the documentation as well! In your `createFromFormat` you're again using an incorrect format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done it with using DateTime::createFromFormat

```
    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $dates[0]);
    $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $dates[1]);
    $newDate = array(
        'start'     => $start->format('Y-m-d'),
        'end'       => $end->format('Y-m-d')
    );

    print_r($newDate) ;
    Array ( [start] => 2020-03-14 [end] => 2020-03-20 )
```

Comment: $output = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '05-03-2021')->format('Y-m-d');

Answer (score -2):

```
$dates = array ('03-14-2020', '03-20-2020' );
  print_r($dates);
      $newDate = array(
         'start'      => date("Y-m-d", time($dates[0])),
         'end'        => date("Y-m-d", time($dates[1]))
      );
  print_r($newDate)
```

Try this

Comment: result is wrong: Array ( [0] => 03-14-2020 [1] => 03-20-2020 ) Array ( [start] => 2020-03-11 [end] => 2020-03-11 )

Comment: Found: You need to use those format for the old dates
- DD-MM-YYYY
- YYYY-MM-DD